# How to display image thumbnail using angular image upload

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-file-upload

I am using **ng2-file-upload** to upload the image. Everything works well but after i choose image, it'll display selected image thumbnail.

Please review my **stackblitz** [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-file-upload?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please update your answer with a code so we can help you in the best way

Comment: can u check link

Comment: i need to show uploaded image thumbnail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer when your image is ready using `FileReader` show the thumbnail

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {FileUploader} from 'ng2-file-upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  url = 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/';
  ready = false;
  thumb="";
  uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: this.url,
    maxFileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1
    });
  name = 'Angular 5';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
      console.log('***** onAfterAddingFile ******')
      var image_file=file._file
      const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      console.log(reader.result)
      this.ready=true;
      this.thumb=reader.result.toString();
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(image_file);
    }

    this.uploader.onCompleteItem =  (item:any, response:any, status:any, headers:any) => {
      console.log('ImageUpload:uploaded:', item, status, response);
    };

    this.uploader.onCompleteAll = () => {
      console.log('******* onCompleteAll *********')
    }

    this.uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = (item: any, filter: any, options: any) => {
      console.log('***** onWhenAddingFileFailed ********')
    }
  }
}
```

Your HTML looks like this

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<p>Maximun allowed file size is 1MB</p>
<img [src]="thumb" *ngIf="ready"/>
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader">


<button (click)="uploader.uploadAll()">Upload </button>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 4):

You can look out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-file-upload-ejdv4y) may this helps you

*Template file*:

`img` element to show image preview

```
<img [src]="previewImg" *ngIf="previewImg"/>
```

*Class file*:

`URL.createObjectURL()` is a static method that creates a DOMString containing a URL representing the object given in the parameter.

`bypassSecurityTrustUrl` Bypass security and trust the given value to be a safe style URL, i.e. a value that can be used in hyperlinks or `<img src>`.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {} // inject the DomSanitizer

 previewImg: SafeUrl;
 this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
      console.log('***** onAfterAddingFile ******')
      this.previewImg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl((window.URL.createObjectURL(file._file)));;
 }
```

Dont forget to include `import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution ,

I have tested on your https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-file-upload  , try this it is working

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
      url = 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/';

      uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: this.url,
        maxFileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1
        });
      name = 'Angular 5';
      //added this two variable here
      imageUrlOfLogo:string='';
      logoFileNameFile?: File;
      ngOnInit() {
        // your own code here
      }
      // added this code here
      handleLogoFileInput(file: any) {
        var item = file.item(0);
        this.logoFileNameFile = file.item(0);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event: any) => {
            this.imageUrlOfLogo = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.logoFileNameFile as File);

    }
}
```

component.html

```
<p>Maximun allowed file size is 1MB</p>
  <img [src]="imageUrlOfLogo" style="width:50%; height:90px;" *ngIf="logoFileNameFile">
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" (change)="handleLogoFileInput($event.target.files)">


<button (click)="uploader.uploadAll()">Upload </button>
```

Comment: What is the difference with the solution approved? it's exactly the same.